# How do I set a switch to turn off a switch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I am trying to set a switch to turn off another switch when it is on. I know you use a if statement to do this, but I find it to be very different than an HTML if statement. I know my code is not right but it will explain what I need.

```
- (IBAction)dashieScheme:(id)sender {

    if(dashieScheme.state = true) {
       (twilightScheme.state = false);

    }
}


- (IBAction)twilightScheme:(id)sender {

    if(twilightScheme:(id)sender ) {
       (dashieScheme.state = false);

    }
}
```

Comment: and html if statement?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the following:

```
[dashieScheme setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

Also, your if statement needs some work.  You want to use == to check for equality.  a single = sign is for assignment.

Comment: where would i place that

Comment: Replace (dashieScheme.state = false); with what I have above

Comment: Similarly replace twilightScheme

Comment: it is saying dashieScheme is undeclared, same with twilightScheme

Comment: I was assuming those were the IBOutlet's to your switches.  Use whatever variable names you use for your switches

Comment: that is what i did i hit control and drug it and named it that, and i am also new to this

Comment: Do you synthesize your IBOutLet in the .m file? If not, it can explain why it tells you your switches are undeclared